# DatabaseException on using getUid() function in Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the id of the logged in user and use it in two fragments. In the fragment I am using first, id gets retrieved and stored in my global variable properly but when I access the other fragment after that, my app crashes saying that getUid() is generating a null pointer exception in the other activity.

Here is my code (Both fragments have identical codes except for different variable names. LDQApp is my class for global variables)

```
public class RecruitmentFragment extends Fragment {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    EditText name_text,reg_text,year_txt, mob_txt,interest_txt;
    Button button;

    public RecruitmentFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recruitment, container, false);

        name_text = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        reg_text = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        year_txt = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        mob_txt = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        interest_txt = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText6);

        button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
       mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("recruitment");

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    LDQApp.uid = firebaseUser.getUid();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String name,regNo,mobNo,interest;
            int year;

            name = name_text.getText().toString();
            regNo = reg_text.getText().toString();
            year = Integer.parseInt(year_txt.getText().toString());
            mobNo = mob_txt.getText().toString();
            interest = interest_txt.getText().toString();

            RecruitUser recruitUser = new RecruitUser(name,regNo,year,mobNo,interest);

            mDatabase.child(LDQApp.uid).setValue(recruitUser);

            mDatabase.child(LDQApp.uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    RecruitUser sUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(RecruitUser.class);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Submitted successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.d(TAG, "User name: " + name + ", Registration No: " + regNo);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    // Failed to read value
                    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

This is the log as requested

[image: Log]

Comment: you said about 2 activities and two fragments yet here i see only one fragment and i dunno its the first one or not?and no log is provided? So how can we give you an answer  ?

Comment: Made a small change. I wanted to write 2 fragments only.
Also, I have written that the other fragment has the same code except for some additional variables. Whichever fragment I access second shows the exception

Comment: as you said you have a value for `LDQApp.uid = firebaseUser.getUid();` in this fragment  and when you acess that on the second one its(`LDQApp.uid`) null  am i right?

Comment: Yes. That is the problem.

Also, @Charuka, I have added the log

Comment: can you try like this, `if (!calledAlready)
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        calledAlready = true; 
    }

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();` ..............use a static boolean and see that  `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` this has been called previously if yes do not call it again .if you can switch between  frags without a exact flow use this for both when one frag called this do not allow the second one to call it again thats the logic

Answer (score 0):

Get your `FirebaseDatabase` like this: 
you don't need to call that and assign new value again an again use a  static one;

```
public class Util {
private static FirebaseDatabase database;

public static FirebaseDatabase getDatabase() {
   if (database == null) {
      database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
      database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
   }
return database;
}

}
```

then you can access this as `Util.getDatabase()` or you can do it keeping a static boolean too as i said in that comment, but this avoids more code redundancy too.

read [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy just create a new class that extends Application

```
public class FireApp extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
/* Enable disk persistence  */
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
}
 }
```

connect it to your project in the manifest file by adding the name attribute

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".FireApp"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume, when using Firebase Authentication, that once a user is logged in, that the user will always be logged in.  Don't store the UID in a global like that.  Wherever you need to know the login status of the user, you typically should use an [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) to keep track of that.  The callback you pass it will always be invoked with the correct login status of the user, and you can react to that information accordingly.

Also, if you are going to use [getCurrentUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()) to try to get the currently logged in user, note that it can return null when the user is not logged in.  That's probably what's happening to you, and why calling getUid() is throwing an NPE for you.